# How to apply Hasura JSON metadata, which was generated from Hasura console, to Hasura docker container?

Tags: kubernetes, metadata, hasura, hasura-docker

I plan to deploy Hasura Docker container into Kubernetes cluster.
So I got a Hasura metadata JSON file (hasura_metadata_2023_02_23_16_59_45_407.json), which was generated form one Hasura via its setting in web console.

My question how can I use this metadata JSON file to automatically pre-configure a Hasura container (which will be created inside a Pod in Kubernetes) each time the container is created ?

The configuration would be something like : connect to multiple databases, set role permissions, set event-trigger ... etc. I want all this configurations to be all finished when the Hasura container is created.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it's not supported yet, here is a ticket about it https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/issues/8423

As an alternative, what you can currently do is to use the yaml metadata files generated by `hasura init .` to automatically pre-configure a Hasura container.

- [doc on how to `hasura init`](https://hasura.io/docs/latest/hasura-cli/commands/hasura_init/)
- [doc on Hasura metadata](https://hasura.io/docs/latest/migrations-metadata-seeds/manage-metadata/)
- [doc on applying migrations and metadata with docker](https://hasura.io/docs/latest/migrations-metadata-seeds/auto-apply-migrations/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `hasura/graphql-engine:<version>.cli-migrations-v3` docker image which will automatically apply metadata and migrations on build.

From the [Hasura docs](https://hasura.io/docs/latest/migrations-metadata-seeds/auto-apply-migrations/)

> The migrations and metadata directories created by the Hasura CLI in a
> Hasura Project can be mounted at the /hasura-migrations and
> /hasura-metadata paths of this Docker container and the container's
> entrypoint script will automatically apply the Migrations and Metadata
> before starting the server. If no directory is mounted at the
> designated paths, the server will start and ignore the Migrations
> and/or Metadata.

Comment: I had seen the doc, it failed every times when I tried to mount metadata or migrations via Docker cli (which files were generated from cli `Hasura int --endpoint ...` of the other project).

Comment: Could you update your question with some detail from the error logs?

Comment: It's kinda long so I wrote it in another answer of this post, could you please help me review it ?
@Kyle Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

My folder structure has all these file generated from Hasura-cli `hasura init ...` : 
 metadata,
migrations,
config.yaml,
seeds

And here's command I use to create Hasura container:

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 \ -v metadata:/hasura-metadata \ -v migrations:/hasura-migrations \ -e HASURA_GRAPHQL_ENABLE_CONSOLE=true \ -e HASURA_GRAPHQL_DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:password@167.xxx.xxx.xxx:5432/postgres \ -e HASURA_GRAPHQL_ADMIN_SECRET=wQuhf5g9T3 \ hasura/graphql-engine:v2.18.0.cli-migrations-v3
```

Here's the error I saw from the Hasura container on Docker Desktop:

```
2023-02-24 14:16:09 {"timestamp":"2023-02-24T07:16:09.000+0000","level":"info","type":"startup","detail":{"kind":"migrations-startup","info":"migrations server port env var is not set, defaulting to 9691"}}
2023-02-24 14:16:09 {"timestamp":"2023-02-24T07:16:09.000+0000","level":"info","type":"startup","detail":{"kind":"migrations-startup","info":"server timeout is not set, defaulting to 30 seconds"}}
2023-02-24 14:16:09 {"timestamp":"2023-02-24T07:16:09.000+0000","level":"info","type":"startup","detail":{"kind":"migrations-startup","info":"starting graphql engine temporarily on port 9691"}}
2023-02-24 14:16:09 {"timestamp":"2023-02-24T07:16:09.000+0000","level":"info","type":"startup","detail":{"kind":"migrations-startup","info":"waiting 30 for 9691 to be ready"}}
2023-02-24 14:16:09 {"detail":{"info":{"admin_secret_set":true,"auth_hook":null,"auth_hook_mode":null,"console_assets_dir":null,"console_sentry_dsn":null,"cors_config":{"allowed_origins":"*","disabled":false,"ws_read_cookie":null},"enable_allowlist":false,"enable_console":true,"enable_maintenance_mode":false,"enable_metadata_query_logging":false,"enable_telemetry":true,"enabled_apis":["metadata"],"enabled_log_types":["startup","webhook-log","http-log","jwk-refresh-log","websocket-log"],"events_fetch_batch_size":100,"experimental_features":[],"graceful_shutdown_timeout":60,"infer_function_permissions":true,"jwt_secret":[],"live_query_options":{"batch_size":100,"refetch_delay":1},"log_level":"info","port":9691,"remote_schema_permissions":false,"server_host":"HostAny","stringify_numeric_types":false,"transaction_isolation":"ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED","unauth_role":null,"use_prepared_statements":true,"v1-boolean-null-collapse":false,"websocket_compression_options":"NoCompression","websocket_connection_init_timeout":"Refined (Seconds {seconds = 3s})","websocket_keep_alive":"KeepAliveDelay {unKeepAliveDelay = Refined (Seconds {seconds = 5s})}"},"kind":"server_configuration"},"level":"info","timestamp":"2023-02-24T07:16:09.811+0000","type":"startup"}
2023-02-24 14:16:10 {"detail":{"info":{"database_url":"postgres://postgres:...@167.xxx.xxx.xxx:5432/postgres","retries":1},"kind":"postgres_connection"},"level":"info","timestamp":"2023-02-24T07:16:09.811+0000","type":"startup"}
2023-02-24 14:16:11 {"detail":{"info":{"message":"source \"motor_db\" has not been initialized yet.","source":"motor_db"},"kind":"source_catalog_migrate"},"level":"info","timestamp":"2023-02-24T07:16:11.511+0000","type":"startup"}
2023-02-24 14:16:12 {"detail":{"info":{"message":"source \"health_db\" has not been initialized yet.","source":"health_db"},"kind":"source_catalog_migrate"},"level":"info","timestamp":"2023-02-24T07:16:11.511+0000","type":"startup"}
2023-02-24 14:16:15 {"detail":{"info":{"message":"source \"user_db\" has not been initialized yet.","source":"user_db"},"kind":"source_catalog_migrate"},"level":"info","timestamp":"2023-02-24T07:16:15.691+0000","type":"startup"}
2023-02-24 14:16:16 {"detail":"Thread sourcePingPoller (re)started","level":"info","timestamp":"2023-02-24T07:16:15.691+0000","type":"unstructured"}
2023-02-24 14:16:16 {"detail":{"info":"Already at the latest catalog version (47); nothing to do.","kind":"catalog_migrate"},"level":"info","timestamp":"2023-02-24T07:16:15.691+0000","type":"startup"}
2023-02-24 14:16:16 {"detail":{"info":"Schema sync enabled. Polling at Refined (Milliseconds {milliseconds = 1s})","kind":"schema-sync"},"level":"info","timestamp":"2023-02-24T07:16:15.691+0000","type":"startup"}
2023-02-24 14:16:16 {"detail":{"info":{"instance_id":"622c5f64-7425-443a-96a9-ce79d9aacd56","message":"listener thread started","thread_id":"ThreadId 50"},"kind":"schema-sync"},"level":"info","timestamp":"2023-02-24T07:16:15.691+0000","type":"startup"}
2023-02-24 14:16:16 {"detail":{"info":{"instance_id":"622c5f64-7425-443a-96a9-ce79d9aacd56","message":"processor thread started","thread_id":"ThreadId 56"},"kind":"schema-sync"},"level":"info","timestamp":"2023-02-24T07:16:15.691+0000","type":"startup"}
2023-02-24 14:16:16 {"detail":{"info":"starting workers","kind":"event_triggers"},"level":"info","timestamp":"2023-02-24T07:16:15.691+0000","type":"startup"}
2023-02-24 14:16:16 {"detail":{"info":"preparing data","kind":"scheduled_triggers"},"level":"info","timestamp":"2023-02-24T07:16:15.691+0000","type":"startup"}
2023-02-24 14:16:16 {"detail":{"info":"Help us improve Hasura! The graphql-engine server collects anonymized usage stats which allows us to keep improving Hasura at warp speed. To read more or opt-out, visit https://hasura.io/docs/latest/graphql/core/guides/telemetry.html","kind":"telemetry"},"level":"info","timestamp":"2023-02-24T07:16:15.691+0000","type":"startup"}
2023-02-24 14:16:16 {"detail":"Thread SchemeUpdate.listener (re)started","level":"info","timestamp":"2023-02-24T07:16:15.691+0000","type":"unstructured"}
2023-02-24 14:16:16 {"detail":"Thread update JWK (re)started","level":"info","timestamp":"2023-02-24T07:16:15.691+0000","type":"unstructured"}
2023-02-24 14:16:16 {"detail":"Thread ourIdleGC (re)started","level":"info","timestamp":"2023-02-24T07:16:15.691+0000","type":"unstructured"}
2023-02-24 14:16:16 {"detail":"Thread SchemeUpdate.processor (re)started","level":"info","timestamp":"2023-02-24T07:16:15.691+0000","type":"unstructured"}
2023-02-24 14:16:16 {"detail":"Thread processEventQueue (re)started","level":"info","timestamp":"2023-02-24T07:16:15.691+0000","type":"unstructured"}
2023-02-24 14:16:16 {"detail":"Thread asyncActionsProcessor (re)started","level":"info","timestamp":"2023-02-24T07:16:15.691+0000","type":"unstructured"}
2023-02-24 14:16:16 {"detail":"Thread asyncActionSubscriptionsProcessor (re)started","level":"info","timestamp":"2023-02-24T07:16:15.691+0000","type":"unstructured"}
2023-02-24 14:16:16 {"detail":"Thread runCronEventsGenerator (re)started","level":"info","timestamp":"2023-02-24T07:16:15.691+0000","type":"unstructured"}
2023-02-24 14:16:16 {"detail":{"info":"Received metadata resource version MetadataResourceVersion {getMetadataResourceVersion = 57} as an initial version. Not updating the schema cache.","thread_type":"processor"},"level":"info","timestamp":"2023-02-24T07:16:15.691+0000","type":"schema-sync"}
2023-02-24 14:16:16 {"detail":"Thread processScheduledTriggers (re)started","level":"info","timestamp":"2023-02-24T07:16:15.691+0000","type":"unstructured"}
2023-02-24 14:16:16 {"detail":"Thread checkForUpdates (re)started","level":"info","timestamp":"2023-02-24T07:16:15.691+0000","type":"unstructured"}
2023-02-24 14:16:17 {"timestamp":"2023-02-24T07:16:17.000+0000","level":"info","type":"startup","detail":{"kind":"migrations-startup","info":"port 9691 is ready"}}
2023-02-24 14:16:17 {"timestamp":"2023-02-24T07:16:17.000+0000","level":"info","type":"startup","detail":{"kind":"migrations-startup","info":"env var HASURA_GRAPHQL_MIGRATIONS_DIR is not set, defaulting to /hasura-migrations"}}
2023-02-24 14:16:17 {"timestamp":"2023-02-24T07:16:17.000+0000","level":"info","type":"startup","detail":{"kind":"migrations-startup","info":"env var HASURA_GRAPHQL_METADATA_DIR is not set, defaulting to /hasura-metadata"}}
2023-02-24 14:16:17 {"timestamp":"2023-02-24T07:16:17.000+0000","level":"info","type":"startup","detail":{"kind":"migrations-apply","info":"applying metadata from /hasura-metadata"}}
2023-02-24 14:16:17 {"detail":{"info":{"message":"starting API server","time_taken":7.123395446},"kind":"server"},"level":"info","timestamp":"2023-02-24T07:16:16.934+0000","type":"startup"}
2023-02-24 14:16:17 {"detail":"Thread runTelemetry (re)started","level":"info","timestamp":"2023-02-24T07:16:16.934+0000","type":"unstructured"}
2023-02-24 14:16:18 {"detail":{"http_info":{"content_encoding":null,"http_version":"HTTP/1.1","ip":"127.0.0.1","method":"GET","status":200,"url":"/v1/version"},"operation":{"request_id":"329e86da-6353-421c-b465-d7305ce1bc7b","request_mode":"non-graphql","response_size":16,"uncompressed_response_size":16},"request_id":"329e86da-6353-421c-b465-d7305ce1bc7b"},"level":"info","timestamp":"2023-02-24T07:16:17.936+0000","type":"http-log"}
2023-02-24 14:16:18 {"detail":{"http_info":{"content_encoding":"gzip","http_version":"HTTP/1.1","ip":"127.0.0.1","method":"POST","status":200,"url":"/v1/query"},"operation":{"query_execution_time":0.245242231,"request_id":"0688a267-1f53-45d4-a4e3-9dd625699188","request_mode":"non-graphql","request_read_time":6.78e-7,"response_size":3067,"uncompressed_response_size":27436,"user_vars":{"x-hasura-role":"admin"}},"request_id":"0688a267-1f53-45d4-a4e3-9dd625699188"},"level":"info","timestamp":"2023-02-24T07:16:17.936+0000","type":"http-log"}
2023-02-24 14:16:18 {"detail":{"http_info":{"content_encoding":null,"http_version":"HTTP/1.1","ip":"127.0.0.1","method":"GET","status":200,"url":"/v1/version"},"operation":{"request_id":"d76729a0-6e8c-41ae-b031-a3b3fa1021a6","request_mode":"non-graphql","response_size":16,"uncompressed_response_size":16},"request_id":"d76729a0-6e8c-41ae-b031-a3b3fa1021a6"},"level":"info","timestamp":"2023-02-24T07:16:17.936+0000","type":"http-log"}
2023-02-24 14:16:18 {"detail":{"http_info":{"content_encoding":null,"http_version":"HTTP/1.1","ip":"127.0.0.1","method":"GET","status":404,"url":"/v1alpha1/config"},"operation":{"error":{"code":"not-found","error":"resource does not exist","path":"$"},"request_id":"9b6971c7-1bb6-499e-bd4e-715bf9957848","request_mode":"error","response_size":65,"uncompressed_response_size":65},"request_id":"9b6971c7-1bb6-499e-bd4e-715bf9957848"},"level":"error","timestamp":"2023-02-24T07:16:17.936+0000","type":"http-log"}
2023-02-24 14:16:19 {"detail":{"http_info":{"content_encoding":null,"http_version":"HTTP/1.1","ip":"127.0.0.1","method":"POST","status":200,"url":"/v1/metadata"},"operation":{"query_execution_time":0.35049015,"request_id":"c74c8780-61b2-44a3-a42c-cc4926e312b5","request_mode":"non-graphql","request_read_time":1.603e-6,"response_size":438,"uncompressed_response_size":438,"user_vars":{"x-hasura-role":"admin"}},"request_id":"c74c8780-61b2-44a3-a42c-cc4926e312b5"},"level":"info","timestamp":"2023-02-24T07:16:18.965+0000","type":"http-log"}
2023-02-24 14:16:19 {"detail":{"http_info":{"content_encoding":null,"http_version":"HTTP/1.1","ip":"127.0.0.1","method":"POST","status":400,"url":"/v1/metadata"},"operation":{"error":{"code":"parse-failed","error":"key \"tables\" not found","path":"$.args.metadata"},"request_id":"bfd71f4c-38bf-4a47-ba12-60b8bf272f1a","request_mode":"error","response_size":83,"uncompressed_response_size":83,"user_vars":{"x-hasura-role":"admin"}},"request_id":"bfd71f4c-38bf-4a47-ba12-60b8bf272f1a"},"level":"error","timestamp":"2023-02-24T07:16:18.965+0000","type":"http-log"}
2023-02-24 14:16:18 {"level":"info","msg":"Help us improve Hasura! The cli collects anonymized usage stats which\nallow us to keep improving Hasura at warp speed. To opt-out or read more,\nvisit https://hasura.io/docs/latest/graphql/core/guides/telemetry.html\n","time":"2023-02-24T07:16:18Z"}
2023-02-24 14:16:18 {"level":"info","msg":"Applying metadata...","time":"2023-02-24T07:16:18Z"}
2023-02-24 14:16:20 time="2023-02-24T07:16:20Z" level=fatal msg="error applying metadata \n{\n  \"code\": \"parse-failed\",\n  \"error\": \"key \\\"tables\\\" not found\",\n  \"path\": \"$.args.metadata\"\n}"
```

Comment: Have you tried deleting the docker volume hosting your database? (Make a backup first if you have data not populated by migrations). I always start with a fresh migration to test my migrations since if a database was manipulated _outside_ of Hasura, it won't have the migration change and starting fresh can make the error more obvious. 

Also, make sure your remote_schemas.yaml file exists, per this GH issue w/ a similar error:  https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/issues/7947

Comment: I had the same error when I was trying to import through hasura-cli the `/hasura-metadata/hasura_metadata_2023_09_03_17_36_08_397.json` file, which was originally exported from the web console's settings tab. Apparently "metadata json" files are not supported for import with hasura-cli yet. I suggest to make sure you don't have any "web-exported json metadata files" in `/hasura-metadata`